# Add a role for a test user

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I have an access token for a FB app that will be used of oAuth registration. Because I do not have a FB account I have created a test account. However when trying to log in using the test users credentials I get this error:

> App Not Setup: This app is still in development mode, and you don't have access to it. Switch to a registered test user or ask an app admin for permissions.

This error is answered in other Stack Overflow questions using the app dashboard. However I don't have access to the dashboard so I decided to add a role for the newly created user by hitting the [roles endpoint](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.10/app/roles).

I have defined the endpoint like this:

```
'https://graph.facebook.com/APP_ID/roles/?access_token=APP_ACCESS_TOKEN&user=TEST_USER_ID&role=testers'
```

The response code is `200`, but when I list the roles of the app nothing is changed, still the admin role is the only role listed. Seems weird that the test user doesn't get a role automatically when created when the associated APP ID and secret are used. I feel like I am missing something here, maybe someone experienced with this can point me in the right direction?

Response:

```
{'data': [{'app_id': 'app_id', 'user': 'app_user_id', 'role': 'administrators'}], 'paging': {'cursors': {'before': 'MAZDZD', 'after': 'MAZDZD'}}}
```

Which is an array of one element, the admin for the app, no test account role found.

**My question is if it's possible to use the graph API in order to register this test user to the app?**

Comment: /roles lists the administrators, developers and testers for this app. A tester is a real user account, that has been assigned the tester role. Do not confuse that with an actual test user, which is a different thing.

Comment: Then my question is if it's possible to use the graph API in order to register this test user to the app?

Comment: Are you talking about an actual test user, or just a normal Facebook profile you created for testing purposes? And why do you not have your own Facebook account, if you want to develop apps on the FB platform? Are you using someone else’s account to administer the app, or what? (That would also violate Facebook terms already.) You should really create your own, personal account that uses your real name first of all, and use that to admin your app. You can test your using that admin account as well.

Comment: Not having a personal account is my choice, that's why test users exist... My client is unreachable for the next day/two and I have seen an explanation that shows how to register a test user from the APP dashboard, I just wanted to do that from the graph API today so that I can start working. Another thing to mention is that when I create the test user the [installed](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.10/app/accounts/test-users) flag is set to true by default. The test user should be able to access...

Comment: No, that is not “why test users exist”. But anyway, how to create them via API is described here, https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/test-users

Comment: Also, the test user created is listed when hitting /app_id/accounts/test-users, but still unable to log in.

Comment: You need to use the password that was shown in response to the request that created the user. (There is also a `login_url` field that you can query - but the URL that returns only works if you are logged in to Facebook using your regular account already.)

Comment: How come when I use the regular FB login I can login with the test user, but when I try to authenticate through the app I get the above mentioned error (and the test user is listed as a test user for that app)? Also, the login_url of the test account isn't working (probably for the reason you mentioned above - need to be logged in with a registered user so that the login url can work).